# reactivemongo BSON writer / reader with arbitrary JSON branch (also using spray)

Tags: mongodb, scala, bson, reactivemongo, spray-json

I am building REST API using spray.  All is working well except this case class:

```
case class User(name: String, places: List[String], data: List[JsObject])
```

The key issue here is the `data` parameter.  It contains a json object with arbitrary number of members, types, and levels - but still valid json.

Using spray, I am able to serialize/deserialize a request/response properly using:

```
object UserProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val userResonseFormat = jsonFormat3(User)
}

// ...

import demo.UserProtocol._

post {
  path("users") {
    entity(as[User]) { user: User =>
      complete(user)
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is reading and writing BSON for reactivemongo.  I cannot seem to figure out how to complete these:

```
implicit object UserWriter extends BSONDocumentWriter[User] {
  def write(user: User): BSONDocument = BSONDocument(
    "name" -> user.name,
    "places" -> user.places,
    "data" -> ???
}

implicit object UserReader extends BSONDocumentReader[User] {
  def read(doc: BSONDocument): User = {
    User(
      doc.getAs[String]("name").get,
      doc.getAs[List[String]]("places").get,
      ???
  }
}
```

In the places of ???, How can I get this arbitrary JSON branch to serialize/deserialize BSON properly for reactivemongo?

Comment: You have to provide BSON/JSON conversions. For Play JSON it can be found in the Play plugin.

Comment: cchantep is referring to https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example that illustrate how to define readers and writers for a model.  Hope it helps.

https://github.com/luongbalinh/play-mongo/blob/master/app/models/User.scala